# Iterating datetime object to generate string

Tags: python, datetime

I have 2 `datetime` objects and I want to create a list of strings that represnt an incrementing between the two datetime objects by the hour. For instance,

```
dt_obj1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 21, 42, 39, 381926)
dt_obj2 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 13, 42, 39, 381926)
```

I want to produce this type of list

```
[
"20151211-2142",
"20151211-2242",
"20151211-2342",
"20151212-0042",
"20151212-0142",
...
]
```

I'm not sure how to update the string when an increment of an hour changes the day, month, or year

Answer (score 3):

I would create a generator, analogous to `range()`, that steps by one hour:

```
import datetime
import pprint

def daterange(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step

dt_obj1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 21, 42, 39, 381926)
dt_obj2 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 13, 42, 39, 381926)

hour = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
result = [date.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M')
          for date in daterange(dt_obj1, dt_obj2, hour)]

pprint.pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [`range_hourly()`](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interface.html?highlight=range_hourly#delorean.range_hourly) function from the awesome [`Delorean` library](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
import datetime

from delorean import range_hourly

dt_obj1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 21, 42, 39, 381926)
dt_obj2 = datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 13, 42, 39, 381926)

for dt in range_hourly(start=dt_obj1, stop=dt_obj2):
    print(dt.datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M"))
```

Prints:

```
20151211-2142
20151211-2242
20151211-2342
20151212-0042
...
20151213-1142
20151213-1242
20151213-1342
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> print pd.DatetimeIndex(start=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 21, 42, 39, 3819
26), end=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 13, 42, 39, 381926), freq=pd.DateOffset
(hours=1)).to_pydatetime()
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 21, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 22, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 11, 23, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 0, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 1, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 2, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 3, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 4, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 5, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 6, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 7, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 8, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 9, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 10, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 11, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 12, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 13, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 14, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 15, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 16, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 17, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 18, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 19, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 20, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 21, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 22, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 12, 23, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 0, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 1, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 2, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 3, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 4, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 5, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 6, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 7, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 8, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 9, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 10, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 11, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 12, 42, 39, 381926),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 13, 13, 42, 39, 381926)], dtype=object)
```